# Am I doing something wrong, or does echo.websocket.org not echo back empty payloads?

Tags: websocket

[According to the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-31) for websockets protocol 13 (RFC 6455), the payload length for any given frame can be 0.

```
                              frame-payload-data     ; n*8 bits in
                                                     ; length, where
                                                     ; n >= 0
```

I am building a websocket client to this spec, but when I sent echo.websocket.org a frame with an empty payload, I get nothing back. I experience the same using [their GUI](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html):

[image: Echo Test GUI]

This is troublesome for me, since the way I'm building my client somewhat requires me to send empty frames when I FIN a multi-frame message.

Is this merely a bug in the Echo Test server? Do a substantial number of server implementations drop frames with empty payloads?

And if this is a bug in Echo Test, does anyone know how I might get in touch with them? The KAAZING site only has tech support contact info for their own products.

Answer (score 0):

If you send a data-frame with no payload, there is nothing to echo back. This behaviour is fully correct. However, it might be standard-conform, too, to send back a dataframe with 0 payload, too. The main question is, if the application layer is informed at all, when a dataframe with no payload is received. This is probably not the case in most implementations.

With TCP this is similar: A TCP-Keepalive is a datagram with 0 payload. It is ack'd by the remote TCP-stack, but the application layer is *not* informed about it (i.e. select() does not return or a read()-syscall remains blocking), which is the expected behaviour.

An application-layer protocol should not rely on the datagrams to structure the data, but should merely expect a stream of bytes without taking regard on how these are transported.

Comment: Conforming to what standard to send back an empty frame? There is no echo standard as far as I know. The echo server IS responding to partial frames (that is, frames without `FIN` set), which I would assume would not be relayed to the application layer. At the very least, I would expect it to echo back a `FIN`. Also, perhaps "client" was a poor word to use. I'm building a transport-layer interface.

Comment: This is what I meant, it is not defined and hence an implementation can decide how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the echo test on websocket.org with empty payloads and it seems to work fine using Chrome, Safari and Firefox (latest versions of each).  Which browser are you using?

Btw, that demo program doesn't abide by any "echo protocol" (afaik), so there's no formal specification that dictates what to do on empty data in a WebSocket set of frames.

If you need help using WebSocket, there are Kaazing forums: http://developer.kaazing.com/forums.

Comment: No browser, I'm using a custom client. What does "work fine" mean? Sending an empty payload in Firefox didn't get anything back for me.

Comment: "work fine" meaning I got an echo back to my browser.  No msg contents of course, but I got a "response".

Comment: That's interesting. I'm reasonably okay with not getting an empty frame echoed back, but since the empty frame was also a FIN it's actually causing the protocol to break down.

Comment: I just tried with Firefox 43.0.4 and got the expected empty-msg response.

Comment: 100% correct. No WS-ECHO standard specification exists (ie, like TCP PING) at this point in time.   Also, the WS server at Websocket.org is fully RFC 6455 compliant and handles partial frames.  The onmessage() is fired for all the frames, even the partial ones.  It is up to the application protocol above this layer to decide whether to expose this information or not.  For example, our JMS library over WS does *not* expose partial frames knowledge at the JMS layer; we handle that "under the hood".  Same with our AMQP and XMPP libraries.   Also... TCP and WS are only roughly analagous.

Comment: I understand this. The only problem is that if you end a fragmented message with an empty frame, the "compliant" echo server will *not* end its echoed fragmented message and will instead start a new message when you send it a new one. This is a violation of the spec.